# Accurate curved arrows in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've created an arrow like the one shown below in Photoshop CS6, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do it? I have lots of these to make and you can see that my current method is very time consuming.

[image]

Comment: You should consider using Illustrator, not only is it faster than any method in photoshop its actually meant for this.

Comment: Do you have access to vector image editing software?  It would be easier to do this in software which is actually designed for this. Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, Sketch (Mac OS only) or the free software Inkscape(dot)org are all capable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also recommend using Illustrator for the arrows. You just have to create a simple vector path with 3 points which can be set to have an attached arrowhead. If you want to do the rest of the work in PS, you can just copy the arrow from Illustrator and use it as a smart vector object in PS. This way the arrow stays fully editable in Illustrator.

[image]